# Multi-word dma 2

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualization

after installation of XP MODE I have in device manager in IDE ATA/ATAPI controler on my SSD disk Multi-word dma 2 mode/same mode like XP mode BIOS/. I using AHCI mode in bios and w7. Its any choice to get back Ultra DMA 6 mode? Thanks for help.

Comment: Are you trying to say: You switched your SATA's BIOS setting to "XP Mode", installed Windows 7, and can not get the setting back to AHCI? Why did you set it to XP Mode in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, thats it. Let's call it "bad idea", as it appeared.

Comment: Since there is a virtualization tag, do you mean that you installed Windows 7's "XP Mode"?